# Animate QML Button component

Tags: c++, qt, qml

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TT
    {
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:
            {
                parent.buttonPressed = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TT.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0


Rectangle
{
    id:ll
    height: 20; width: 100

    property bool buttonPressed: false

    Button
    {
        id: redRect
        background: Rectangle
                    {
                        height: 20; width: 100
                        color: "red"
                        border.width: 2
                    }

        anchors.fill: parent

        states: State {
                name: "pressed"; when: ll.buttonPressed
                PropertyChanges { target: redRect; scale: 1.2 ; }
            }

        transitions: Transition
        {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "scale"; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to animate the button through **main.qml**.
When I write `buttonPressed = true`, the problem is that it stays true always.

Where am I supposed to set it to false so that when I click again it animates again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@splaytreez's answer works, and he's right to recommend getting rid of your `buttonPressed` property and the extraneous `MouseArea`. I wanted to offer an alternative solution because I often find states and transitions hard to follow as code grows and becomes more complicated. A more direct approach is to create animation objects and call them directly.

```
    Button {
        id: redRect
        onPressed: anim.start()

        SequentialAnimation {
            id: anim

            // Expand the button
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: redRect
                property: "scale"
                to: 1.2
                duration: 200
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }

            // Shrink back to normal
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: redRect
                property: "scale"
                to: 1.0
                duration: 200
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Transition` has a property `running`. You can try something like this:

```
transitions: Transition
{
    NumberAnimation { 
        properties: "scale";
        duration: 200; 
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    }

    onRunningChanged: {
        if (!running) buttonPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Now, do you actually need this property at all? Have you considered using `onPressed` signal:

```
Button {
    // ...
    onPressed: {
        state = "pressed"
    }
    // ...
}
```

This way the state will be changed whenever the button is pressed (as it was before) and you don't need to use the `buttonPreessed` property.